# How to hide entered password value from logs of an InstallShield Suite/Advanced UI setup

Tags: installation, installshield, suite

Is there a way to hide some sensitive properties from logging in InstallShield Suite/Advanced UI projects when using /debuglog command line?
Something similar to MsiHiddenProperties for MSI projects?

Scenario:

- Using InstallShield 2015 Premier for Windows
- There is a PasswordBox control bound to an installer property (you know, the one obscuring the value on the UI)

Problems:
The password is written to the setup log in clear-text when:

- PROBLEM 1: the user changes the value of the PasswordBox
- PROBLEM 2: the password value is passed forward to the MSI command line

Right now the log output looks like this:

```
10-11-2021[10:58:25 AM]: Engine: property 'ServiceAccountPassword' value now 'm'
10-11-2021[10:58:25 AM]: Engine: property 'ServiceAccountPassword' value now 'my'
10-11-2021[10:58:26 AM]: Engine: property 'ServiceAccountPassword' value now 'myp'
10-11-2021[10:58:26 AM]: Engine: property 'ServiceAccountPassword' value now 'mypa'
10-11-2021[10:58:26 AM]: Engine: property 'ServiceAccountPassword' value now 'mypas'
10-11-2021[10:58:26 AM]: Engine: property 'ServiceAccountPassword' value now 'mypass'
10-11-2021[10:58:26 AM]: Engine: property 'ServiceAccountPassword' value now 'mypassw'
10-11-2021[10:58:27 AM]: Engine: property 'ServiceAccountPassword' value now 'mypasswo'
10-11-2021[10:58:27 AM]: Engine: property 'ServiceAccountPassword' value now 'mypasswor'
10-11-2021[10:58:27 AM]: Engine: property 'ServiceAccountPassword' value now 'mypassword'

10-11-2021[10:59:27 AM]: Final command line: REBOOT=ReallySuppress TRANSFORMS=1033.mst SERVICEPASSWORD="mypassword" <rest of command line removed>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

There is an '**ISHiddenProperties**' property for InstallShield Suite setups.

Tried out, works.

Link to [Official Revenara documentation](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/ISHiddenProperties.htm)

Text from official documentation:

> *To prevent a property from being written in the log file:*
>
> 1. In the View List under **Behavior and Logic**, click **Property Manager**.
> 2. In the **Name** column, find the **ISHiddenProperties** property.
>
>    If this property is not listed, click the **New Property** button to create this property, and in the **Name** column, enter `ISHiddenProperties`.
> 3. In the **Value** column, enter the name of the property whose value you do not want to be logged; ensure that you use the same capitalization.
>    To list more than one property, separate each with a semicolon (;).
>
> Note that **ISHiddenProperties** is useful for prevention of logging for
> values in the following scenarios:
>
> • The value of the property changes.
>
> • The end user sets the value of
> the property through command line when launching the Advanced UI or
> Suite/Advanced UI Setup.exe file.
>
> • The property is configured through a command line that the Advanced UI or Suite/Advanced UI installation
> passes to a package. This is configurable in the Packages view, on the
> Common tab, in the Operation area.

> If the property is logged through
> ISuiteExtension::LogInfo, the Suite engine cannot prevent the logging.
> Therefore, any code that you create to write a property value to the
> log file should read **ISHiddenProperties** to see whether the property
> value should be logged.